# Dynamic Programming algorithm for Longest Common Subsequence in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, multidimensional-array, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to write a dynamic programming algorithm for the Longest Common Subsequence.
The return should be the length of this subsequence.
But my algorithm always returns 0. I couldn't find the error.

```
public static int LCS(String A, String B, int m, int n) {
    int table[][] = new int[m + 1][n + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        table[i][0] = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        table[0][n] = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (A.charAt(i) == B.charAt(j)) {
                table[i][j] = table[i - 1][j - 1] + 1;
            } else {
                table[i][j] = max(table[i][j - 1], table[i - 1][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    return table[m][n];
}

private static int max(int a, int b) {
    return (a > b) ? a : b;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Your input words:\n");
    String x = in.nextLine();
    String y = in.nextLine();

    in.close();

    int m = x.length();
    int n = y.length();

    System.out.println("Length of LCS is " + LCS(x, y, m, n));
}
```

Comment: What values did you test with?

Comment: What does your `table` look like before the method returns?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you implemented [this algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem#Computing_the_length_of_the_LCS), but have a few errors:

- Your loops should be `1..m` and `1..n` **inclusive**, meaning you need to change `<` to `<=`.
- `charAt()` is zero-based, so you need `charAt(i - 1)` and `charAt(j - 1)`.

These are not errors, but:

- The loops to initialize to 0 are unnecessary in Java. `table` is already initialized to all zeroes by the `new` operator.
- No need to implement `max()`, since it's already implemented as `Math.max()`.

So, here is the result, using names from the linked article:

```
public static int LCS(String X, String Y) {
    final int m = X.length();
    final int n = Y.length();
    int[][] C = new int[m + 1][n + 1];
    for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
            if (X.charAt(i - 1) == Y.charAt(j - 1))
                C[i][j] = C[i - 1][j - 1] + 1;
            else
                C[i][j] = Math.max(C[i][j - 1], C[i - 1][j]);
    return C[m][n];
}
```

**TEST**

```
System.out.println(LCS("This is a test", "Does it work ok?"));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
5
```

Here is the matching letters of the longest common subsequence:

```
This is a test
   ↑↑↑ ↑ ↑
   ↓↓↓ ↓    ↓
Does it work ok?
```

Answer (score 0):

The conditions in the `for` loops use `i < m` or `j < n`.

As a consequence `i` is never equal to `m` and `j` is never equal to `n`, so `table[m][n]` is never modified inside these loops, right?

The value returned is the value at `table[m][n]` which is never modified: `0`.